# Heroku git push - "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

Trying to host a site with Heroku. Heroku has received the app after

`git commit`
but it wont finalize when I put:
`git push heroku master`

Here is output I receive:

```
Enumerating Objects: 51, done.
Counting Objects: 100% (51/51), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 504
Fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (51/51), 48.24 MiB | 13 KiB/s, done.
Total 51 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, it looks like there is a problem with your keys, you need to upload your current key to heroku

```
 heroku keys:add
```

Details at "Managing Your SSH Keys": https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys